# Need to create file using golang which will live for a short duration

Tags: file, go, scheduler

I am creating golang cli application for which I am suppose to create file which should live for a short duration (i.e. 1 min or 5 mins) and after that it should automatically gets deleted and as far as I have seen golang os module is not providing such functionality can you let me know some approach that I can use to make such functionality available

I have searched stackoverflow and other other websites to find the same functionality but no luck yet

Comment: No language I know of provides such functionality. Probably because there is no portable way of doing it? Why exactly do you need that?

Comment: thanks for responding basically I am storing some data like id, password and webserver name and it will behave as session for users

Comment: The OS will not automatically clean it up for you. There are several ways you can do this: you can use an in-memory program to store those for you for some time, and it forgets after a few mins, something like memcached, or a custom program you write.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux You can write .sh script with command:

```
find /dir -type f -mmin -5 -delete
```

This command delete all files in /dir older then 5 minits.
And then add your .sh script to cron.